# Bash VPN accepting HTML conditions

Tags: html, bash

I am trying to configure my Linux server to connect via a VPN using the following command:

```
sudo pppd pty "pptp UKIPVPN.com --nolaunchpppd" file /etc/ppp/options.pptp user ukipvpn.com password freevpn
```

Using ifconfig I can confirm the pppd connection is established:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
      inet addr:10.162.0.74  P-t-P:10.162.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1496  Metric:1
      RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
      RX bytes:60 (60.0 B)  TX bytes:66 (66.0 B)
```

I have added the ppp0 to the route using:
    $ sudo route add default ppp0

The issue I have is that the VPN normally serves a HTML 'I accept' page before allowing a connection to the internet.

The page is served every time I try and connect to any pages from the CLI:

```
curl ipecho.net/plain                                           
<html>
<head><title>UFreeVPN.COM Service from UK</title></head>
<br>
<br>
<font color=blue><center>            <h1>UFreeVPN.COM Service from UK</h1> </center></font>

 <center><h2><a href='http://uk.ufreevpn.com'>I Agree</a> to use the Free VPN Service</h2></center>



<center><font size='2'>No illegal activities allowed. In case of abuse, users' VPN access log is subjected to expose to related authorities.</font></center>
```

Is there a way I can 'Agree' from Bash to allow this connection to work?

EDIT:

Having checked the source of the "I agree" page it is just as returned by curl above with no Javascript etc.

On clicking I agree you get auto redirected to http://www.ukipvpn.com.

I tried the following:

```
 curl http://www.ukipvpn.com
```

and     curl http://www.ukipvpn.com -e--referer

but each time i try and grab a page with curl then I am presented with the "I agree" page from the vpn.

Comment: Is that the whole page? Nothing else? No javascript? If that's it then clicking that link just takes you to another page and you should be able to fetch that page directly to continue (possibly with referer set).

Comment: I think that's the whole page. I will look at it on my desktop machine and see what I can find. Can you give an example implementation with referer set?

Comment: The curl `-e/--referer` flag is what you want for that and I would see what your browser sends (if anything) and send that. But you might not need it. Try without it first.

Comment: Edited to update the progress, sadly the curl -e/--referer for the i agree page didnt work

Comment: The flag isn't `-e--referer`. The argument is *either* `-e <referer_url>` *or* `--referer=<referer_url>` where `<referer_url>` is the URL of the page that sent you there (probably `http://www.ukipvpn.com` or `http://uk.ufreevpn.com` or `http://ufreevpn.com` or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading around slightly more on curl the key is to use the POST data function:

```
curl --data "button=%20I%20AGREE%20&sessionid=<SESSION ID HERE>" http://www.ukipvpn.com
```

Now the VPN accepts requests and is working.  Thanks for the help.
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html